# pandas - pivot column names as values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
      1     2     3     4     5     6
     Ax    Ax    Ax    Ax    Ax    Ax
  delta delta delta delta delta delta
0     6     4     1     5     3     2
1     6     1     5     3     2     4
2     6     1     5     3     2     4
3     6     1     5     3     2     4
4     6     1     5     3     2     4
5     6     1     5     3     2     4
6     6     1     5     3     2     4
7     6     1     5     3     2     4
8     6     1     5     3     2     4
9     6     1     5     3     2     4
```

I would like to pivot this such that the values are the column, and the columns are the value.

So, the first two rows would become the following:

```
      1     2     3     4     5     6
0     3     6     5     2     4     1
1     3     6     2     5     4     1
```

I hope that this makes sense. I have tried using pivot() and pivot_table() but it doesn't seem possible with that.

Comment: Your second row doesn't seem to be correct in your sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel([1,2])

df1.stack().reset_index().pivot(index='level_0', columns=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slice the columns by the sorted indices:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cols = df.columns.get_level_values(0).to_numpy()
pd.DataFrame(cols[np.argsort(df.to_numpy(), 1)],
             columns=list(range(1, df.shape[1]+1)))

   1  2  3  4  5  6
0  3  6  5  2  4  1
1  2  5  4  6  3  1
2  2  5  4  6  3  1
3  2  5  4  6  3  1
4  2  5  4  6  3  1
5  2  5  4  6  3  1
6  2  5  4  6  3  1
7  2  5  4  6  3  1
8  2  5  4  6  3  1
9  2  5  4  6  3  1
```